# Flutter Streams, how to access previously emitted data from the stream

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sliver, rxdart

I have a stream builder, and i want to access the previously emitted value from the stream. If one is familiar with distinct, they must know that distinct basically checks if previous and current value is the same. I want access to the previous value. To create my own custom condition.

I am using replay-subject from RxDart with a max capacity : 2. No whenever i add something to the sink of the stream using sink.add(data); all the instances of replay-subject are replaced by the new data. thus, i do not have access to the previous data, it just gets overridden. I am stuck need help in how to add data to the replay subject. if not using sink.add() method

Comment: May be you are looking for ReplaySubject<T> class

Comment: Yes, i am. However, whenever i try to add an event to replaySubject. It adds to the entire list. For example if i add "123" to a replaysubject with max capacity:2. then replaysubject.values will be ["1", "1"] and if i do sink.add(2), this changes the entire thing to ["2","2"]. I just want the replaysubject to hold ["1","2"] for me.

Comment: I think you are recreating your replay subject every time you add an event to it could you please provide your code

Comment: I created https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/issues/205

Answer (score 1):

Per [GitHub ticket filed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/issues/205), this buggy behavior [should be fixed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/issues/205#issuecomment-446744328) by [rxdart 0.20.0 release](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/issues/205#issuecomment-446744328).

Also, as mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/issues/205#issuecomment-446264053), I believed the issue could be answered by [#210](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/pull/210) and should be available now.

> This fix should properly handle `buffer` on `count` and `window` on
> `count`, when using the `startBufferEvery` parameter.
>
> This *is* a breaking change:
>
> - startBufferEvery should now work correctly
> - when the parent `Stream` completes, we no longer add the remainder `buffer` as a final `event`:   i.e. if the `buffer` is set to group by
>   3 events, and the parent `Stream` outputs `1, 2, 3, 4`, then the only
>   `event` on `buffer(3)` would be `[1, 2, 3]`. Before, we would also
>   dispatch `[4]` as the remainder `onDone`.